# Is there a way I could effectively visualize the test report generated by gradle?

Tags: gradle, data-visualization, build-automation, ui-automation

I have a gradle task that generates a summary.html file which has package level report which is a representation of the test coverage by the automation project. I want to visualize this report in a more sensible way. Is there a better and easier way to do this? I just feel that better data visualization would help our team make better decisions and provide a good representation of code coverage.

Comment: You can use SonarQube

Comment: for CI environment you can generate the xml report instead of html. usually jenkins and co do a good job in visualising the test results in a more sensible way. If you want to have a custom report, I'd also go with the xml report and use xslt for applying custom report layout on top.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam can you explain a little more how I could utilize SonarQube with gradle. I have never used SonarQube